# I get a nonsense when i try to invert my number

Tags: arrays, c, loops, if-statement

Im getting "-1005348639" when i try to invert the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numero, numero_invertido,digito;
    printf("numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    if(numero>999){
        while(numero>0){
            digito=numero%10;
            numero=numero/10;
            numero_invertido=numero_invertido*10+digito;
        }
        printf("El numero invertido es %d", numero_invertido);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I Cant think in any solution

Comment: You never initialized `numero_invertido` to whatever you want its start value to be.

Comment: Try changing the first line to `int numero, numero_invertido=0,digito;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `numero_invertido` to value 0 first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int numero, numero_invertido = 0,digito;
    printf("numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    if(numero>999){
        while(numero>0){
            digito=numero%10;
            numero=numero/10;
            numero_invertido=numero_invertido*10+digito;
        }
        printf("El numero invertido es %d", numero_invertido);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

If you did not initialized it to zero, it will just take some garbage value and cause all sort of undefined behavior's